# Extracting segments of a semver version string via Java regex

Tags: java, regex, semantic-versioning

Java 8 here. I am trying to parse a [semver](https://semver.org/) (or at least, my flavor of semver) string and extract out its main segments:

- Major version number
- Minor version number
- Patch number
- Qualifier (`RC`, `SNAPSHOT`, `RELEASE`, etc.)

Here is my code:

```java
String version = "1.0.1-RC";
Pattern versionPattern = Pattern.compile("^[1-9]\\d*\\.\\d+\\.\\d+(?:-[a-zA-Z0-9]+)?$");
Matcher matcher = versionPattern.matcher(version);

if (matcher.matches()) {

    System.out.println("\n\n\matching version is: " + matcher.group(0));
    System.out.println("\nmajor #: " + matcher.group(1));
    System.out.println("\nminor #: " + matcher.group(2));
    System.out.println("\npatch #: " + matcher.group(3));
    System.out.println("\nqualifier: " + matcher.group(4) + "\n\n\n");

}
```

When this runs, I get the following output on the console:

```
matching version is: 1.0.1-RC
2019-10-18 14:32:05,952 [main] 84b37cef-70f9-4ab8-bafb-005821699766 ERROR c.s.f.s.listeners.StartupListener - java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: No group 1
```

What do I need to do to my regex and/our use of the Matcher API so that I can extract:

- `1` as the major number
- `0` as the minor number
- `1` as the patch number
- `RC` as the qualifier

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NOTE:

- You should not escape `m` in a string literal, `\m` is not a valid string escape sequence and the code won't compile
- `Matcher#matches()` requires a full string match, no need to add `^` and `$` anchors
- To be able to reference `Matcher#group(n)`, you need to define the groups in the pattern in the first place. Wrap the parts you need with pairs of unescaped parentheses.

Use

```
String version = "1.0.1-RC";
Pattern versionPattern = Pattern.compile("([1-9]\\d*)\\.(\\d+)\\.(\\d+)(?:-([a-zA-Z0-9]+))?");
Matcher matcher = versionPattern.matcher(version);

if (matcher.matches()) {
    System.out.println("matching version is: " + matcher.group(0));
    System.out.println("major #: " + matcher.group(1));
    System.out.println("minor #: " + matcher.group(2));
    System.out.println("patch #: " + matcher.group(3));
    System.out.println("qualifier: " + matcher.group(4) + "\n\n\n");
}
```

See the [Java demo](https://ideone.com/OdXvGB), output:

```
matching version is: 1.0.1-RC
major #: 1
minor #: 0
patch #: 1
qualifier: RC
```

Answer (score 1):

I was looking around on the semver specification [website](https://semver.org/) and found a regex there that works, and i fixed it a little to work with java regex named groups and here is the regex if anyone needs it

```
final static String version_regex = "^(?<major>0|[1-9]\\d*)\\.(?<minor>0|[1-9]\\d*)\\.(?<patch>0|[1-9]\\d*)(?:-(?<prerelease>(?:0|[1-9]\\d*|\\d*[a-zA-Z-][0-9a-zA-Z-]*)(?:\\.(?:0|[1-9]\\d*|\\d*[a-zA-Z-][0-9a-zA-Z-]*))*))?(?:\\+(?<buildmetadata>[0-9a-zA-Z-]+(?:\\.[0-9a-zA-Z-]+)*))?$";

// After matching to grab the groups
String mayor = matcher.group("major");
String minor = matcher.group("minor");
String patch = matcher.group("patch");
String prerelease = matcher.group("prerelease");
String buildmetadata = matcher.group("buildmetadata");
```